# xml abrindo em div não recebe xsl

Tags: javascript, xml

Tenho os arquivos HTML, `ajax.js` e `intrucao.js` como segue.

Ao clicar em `agar.xml` a folha de estilo `agar.xsl` não é carregada.

O adendo é que o carregamento é feito em uma `div`.
O que há no código que deva ser mudado?

Tenho um HTML conforme segue:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Carregando Página em DIV / AJAX</title>
<script language="javascript" src="ajax.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="instrucao.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="menu"><a href="#" onclick="abrirPag('agar.xml');">xml</a></div>
        <br><br>
    <div id="conteudo_mostrar"></div>
</body>
```

O arquivo `ajax.js`:

```
function GetXMLHttp() {
    if(navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
        xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    else {
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    return xmlHttp;
}

var xmlRequest = GetXMLHttp();
```

O arquivo `instrucao.js`:

```
function abrirPag(valor){
    var url = valor;

    xmlRequest.open("GET",url,true);    
    xmlRequest.onreadystatechange = mudancaEstado;
    xmlRequest.send(null);

        if (xmlRequest.readyState == 1) {
            document.getElementById("conteudo_mostrar").innerHTML = "<img src='loader.gif'>";
        }

    return url;
}

function mudancaEstado(){
    if (xmlRequest.readyState == 4){
        document.getElementById("conteudo_mostrar").innerHTML = xmlRequest.responseText;
    }
}
```

Comment: algum  erro  no  console ? va uma olhada aperta f12

Comment: Não há erro apresentado.